# ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I have been trying to load data into HBase table using Pig. I have added the Pig classpath referencing the HBase libraries and tried running the Pig script in local mode. I have first created a table 'weather' in HBase with 'info' column family.

The Pig classpath referencing  HBase libraries is:

```
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$PIG_INSTALL/pig-0.13.0-h1.jar:$HBASE_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR/lib/*:$PIG_CLASSPATH
```

The Pig Script is as follows:

```
data = LOAD '/home/uzair/200707hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
temp_info = FOREACH data GENERATE $1, $10;
rank = RANK temp_info;
final = FILTER rank BY $0 IS NOT NULL;
STORE final INTO 'hbase://weather' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('info:date info:temp');
```

When I run this script using pig -x local -f /home/uzair/pigload.pig, I get the following error:

```
14/09/25 14:05:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
14/09/25 14:05:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked LOCAL as the ExecType
2014-09-25 14:06:00,247 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.13.0 (r1606446) compiled Jun 29 2014, 02:29:34
2014-09-25 14:06:00,253 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/uzair/pig_1411634160241.log
2014-09-25 14:06:04,061 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/uzair/.pigbootup not found
2014-09-25 14:06:04,444 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
2014-09-25 14:06:08,717 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
2014-09-25 14:06:08,718 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=ubuntu
2014-09-25 14:06:08,718 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_45
2014-09-25 14:06:08,718 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2014-09-25 14:06:08,719 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.home=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
2014-09-25 14:06:08,719 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/tools.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/..:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../conf:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/pig-0.13.0-h1.jar:/lib/*:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/lib/native/lib/*:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/pig-0.13.0-h1.jar:/lib/*:/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/lib/native/lib/*::/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/accumulo-core-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/accumulo-fate-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/accumulo-server-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/accumulo-start-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/accumulo-trace-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/avro-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/avro-mapred-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/avro-tools-1.7.5-nodeps.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/hbase-0.94.1.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/js-1.7R2.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/piggybank.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/pig-0.13.0/bin/../pig-0.13.0-withouthadoop-h1.jar:
2014-09-25 14:06:08,720 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/home/uzair/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
2014-09-25 14:06:08,720 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2014-09-25 14:06:08,720 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2014-09-25 14:06:08,720 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
2014-09-25 14:06:08,720 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2014-09-25 14:06:08,721 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=3.13.0-36-generic
2014-09-25 14:06:08,721 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=uzair
2014-09-25 14:06:08,721 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/home/uzair
2014-09-25 14:06:08,721 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/home/uzair
2014-09-25 14:06:08,724 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
2014-09-25 14:06:08,940 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper - The identifier of this process is 5252@ubuntu
2014-09-25 14:06:08,958 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-09-25 14:06:09,040 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2014-09-25 14:06:09,091 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x148abe93714000d, negotiated timeout = 90000
2014-09-25 14:16:49,174 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat - org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for weather,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
2014-09-25 14:16:49,238 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for weather,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
Details at logfile: /home/uzair/pig_1411634160241.log
```

[Edit]The Pig stack trace:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for weather,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for weather,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.getOutputFormat(HBaseStorage.java:890)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.InputOutputFileValidatorVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidatorVisitor.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan.validate(LogicalPlan.java:210)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.compile(PigServer.java:1744)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$300(PigServer.java:1420)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1333)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:375)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:232)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:479)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for weather,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:841)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:201)
    ... 27 more
================================================================================
```

The HBase installation is in Pseudo distribution mode using HBase managed Zookeeper. I do not know what I am missing here. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information such as master or region server logs.

Thanks
Uzair Syed

Comment: do jps and check if hregionserver is running

Comment: Yeah.. It is running..

Comment: check your hbase regionservers file, is localhost there

Comment: Yes, it has localhost inside it. I can create table and put the values inside the columns manually but it does not work with Pig :(

Comment: what does the pig_1411634160241.log say in the recent exception

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with Pig log..

Comment: copy pig libs to hbase libs and rerun hbase-server